# jsPDF page formatting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf

The below code pixelates the output / stretches resolution. 
I can't find any option to print the correct resolution.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('printableTable');
    html2canvas(input).then((canvas) => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        const pdf = new jsPDF();
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'png', 0, 0, 210, 297);
        pdf.save("download.pdf");
    });
```

Comment: Please explain in greater detail what you actually are asking for.

Comment: I guess you simply need to replace `210` and `297` with your image's actual width and height

Comment: @YohanesGultom That might be the case. but I don't know the actual size of the image :-( I am rendering the Div.

Comment: @U.Windl sure, I am rendering  a table and using jsPDF to convert that table into PDF. I can convert the table into pdf using jsPDF but the image of the table inside pdf is stretched.

Comment: @As3Script based on following link, the size of the image equals to the canvas size. So I guess you can just pass the canvas' width and height https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916126/set-size-of-image-from-canvas